# Binary classification with imbalanced dataset, about lightgbm output probability distribution

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression, class-imbalance, lightgbm

I trained a binary classifier for an imbalanced dataset. I did two experiments:

1. **lightgbm classifier, boosting_type='gbdt', objective='cross_entropy', SMOTE upsample**

After training the lgbm model, I made predictions on validation dataset. I plotted the probability distribution as follow:

[lightgbm output probability distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrUGh.png)

Plot code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
tmp = pd.Series(pred_y)
ax = tmp.plot.kde()
fig.savefig('xx.png')
```

2. **Standard Scaler, sklearn logistic regression, class_weight='balanced'**

The output probability distribution of validation dataset is as follow:

[logistic output probability distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1rb2.png)

Why does the lightgbm output probability distribution have some output values near 0.5 and 0.75?
Unlike a logistic model, just output probability either near 0, or near 1. For that lightgbm model is a decision forest, and add many outputs from many trees to produce the final probability?
Or is it because the dataset is imbalanced?

[differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pk51.png)

Comment: Maybe because the LGBM model can classify them as either 1 or 0. Maybe they lie in between the 0 and 1 category.

Comment: It's wonderful to be able to say with high confidence that an observation belongs to a particular category. However, that might not be realistic. The LightGBM model is not just reporting "definitely category 0" and "definitely category 1". The LightGBM is reporting that there are cases where it is not so sure. How do the models compare on a proper scoring rule like log loss or Brier score? // [Class imbalance is not the issue here or even much of an issue at all.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he)

Comment: It's conceivable that SMOTE is muddying the class separation.  LightGBM supports `class_weight="balanced"` as well, so what happens when you try that instead of SMOTE?